# Should I use datetime or timestamp for creation and modification dates?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, creation

I already read all the documentation and previous answers but all they explain are the technical differences and not what the common use is for...

I want to save creation and modification date. Should I use `datetime` and `timestamp`?!?! Or `timestamp` for both?

I understand that if creation date doesn't change I should use `datetime`, but I've seen some people use timestamp too.

Thanks in advance, Leandro.

Comment: datetime will store the value as per your server's timezone. Timestamp will always store in UTC. If your application code does not really need to handle various timezones, you can simply use datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `timestamp` for both.

It can be confusing switching between `timestamp` and `datetime`, so it's easier to just keep everything the same.

Note that some limitations of `timestamp` is that it has a [range](https://www.eversql.com/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-column-types-which-one-i-should-use/) of `1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC`. This can be troublesome if you're dealing with birthdays and the like (that would be a use case for `datetime`).

An advantage of `timestamp` is that it's always converted to UTC. So if you're serving data to different timezones it's automatically converted to their respective location.